# Substitute string when one input string is substring of other input string

Tags: perl, sed

How to do replacement using `sed` or `perl` with multiple input strings and one string is substring of other string.

Example:

Input :  `a[b][c]`

Expected Output: `a.*b.*c.*`

I tried following but the `][` between b and c is  messing up the results.

```
echo "a[b][c]" |sed -r 's/[\[\]]{1}|\[|\]/.*/g'
a.*b.*.*c.*
echo "a[b][c]" |sed -r 's/[\[\]]|\[|\]/.*/g'
a.*b.*.*c.*
```

I  was hoping is someone could help, Thanks. preferring `perl` solution as I have to fit this into rest of the unshared code.

Comment: `echo a[b][c] | perl -pe "s/([\[\]]+)/.*/g"` produces `a.*b.*c.*`

Comment: This is possible, too: `echo 'a[b][c]' | perl -pe 's/[][]+/.*/g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "a[b][c]" | sed 's/]/.*/g; s/\[/.*/; s/\[//g'
```

Output:

```
a.*b.*c.*
```

Or replace `sed` with `perl -pe`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\[|\]\[?/.*/g' file
```

Replace either `[` or `]` followed by zero or one `[` by `.*`.